# Using LuaRocks in Windows

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am trying to use LuaRocks. I am using lua5.1. I just click the install.bat after downloading the win file of LuaRocks. When I run luarocks in cmd, it says "The system cannot find specified path." I already added the path in the Enviroment Variables where you can find luarocks.bat. What do you think is wrong? I need your help.Here are the images:

[image: Files image]

and

[image: CMD image]

What do you thinks is wrong? Do you think it has something to do with the config file?

```
*rocks_trees = {
    { name = [[user]],
         root    = home..[[C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks]],
    },
    { name = [[system]],
         root    = [[C:\gcc-lua-install\lua\lua-5.1]],
    },
}
variables = {
    MSVCRT = 'MSVCRT',
    LUALIB = 'lua51.lib'
}
verbose = false   -- set to 'true' to enable verbose output*
```

Comment: ` root    = home..[[` seems not correct. Also checkout luarocks.bat file. If you use msvc compiler I can suggest my luaenv project https://github.com/moteus/lua-windows-environment

Comment: Hello. Thanks for reply. I manage to install luarocks, I just forgot last time to add all paths given in the instruction while installing. Now I am having a problem installing luasql. I use the following command: luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\include"  MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib". You said in git that "You must replace "mysqlclient" with "libmysql" in luasql-mysql rockspec." Where is the luasql-mysql rockspec. It would be really helpful thanks.

Comment: I never build MySQL. rockspec uses `mysqlclient` as link name. If you use MSVS you have to point `MYSQL_LIBDIR` to path where `mysqlclient.lib` is. For MinGW you can point to `mysqlclient.dll`. If there no such lib but exists `libmysql.lib` You can try use it. Just copy/rename file or edit rockspec. May be Windows mysql dist uses different name.

Comment: I am failing to install luarocks  with lua 5.3.4 on w7 - lua itself works perfectly. Installer is needlessly complicated and not friendly, documentation is ambiguous not helpful either.
vars.VERSION = "2.4"

Comment: Would be nice not to require admin rights to install luarocks (for one user)